# Node, AngularJS, express, mongoDB basic user registration page, POST not working

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mongodb, express

I'm trying to build a basic registration page using node.js, express, mongoDB and AngularJS.

Before I tried to implement this registration functionality, I was using Angular routing for my views.

See the contents of my app.routes file below...

```
angular.module('app.routes', [])

  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when("/", {
        templateUrl: "views/Login.html"
      })
      .when("/Register", {
        templateUrl: "views/Register.html"
      })
      .when("/Home", {
        templateUrl: "views/Home.html",
        controller: "homeController"
      })
      .when("/CocktailDetails", {
        templateUrl: "views/CocktailDetails.html",
        controller: "cocktailDetailsController"
      })
      .when("/Favourites", {
        templateUrl: "views/Favourites.html",
        controller: "favouritesController"
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: "/"
      })

  })
```

When the app loads it will direct the user to a login page, if they don't have an account there's a link to go the register page, url for this page is http://localhost:3000/#!/Register.

Please see view for the Register page below...

```
<div class="main">
    <p class="sign" align="center">Register</p>
    <form class="form1" action="/Register" method="POST">
        <input class="un " type="email" align="center" placeholder="Email" name="username" required>
        <input class="pass" type="password" align="center" placeholder="Password" name="password" required>
        <a class="submit" align="center">Register</a>
</div>
```

So when they click the submit link/button it will perform a POST request, to create a new user in the userDB.

Please see server.js file content below...

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}))
app.use(express.static('node_modules'));
app.use(express.static('public'));

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/userDB", { useNewUrlParser: true });

const userSchema = {
    email: String,
    password: String
};

const User = new mongoose.model("User", userSchema);


//Routes

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.render("Login");
});

app.get("/Register", function (req, res) {
    res.render("Register");
});

app.get("/Home", function (req, res) {
    res.render("Home");
});
app.get("/CocktailDetails", function (req, res) {
    res.render("CocktailDetails");
});
app.get("/Favourites", function (req, res) {
    res.render("Favourites");
});

app.use(router);

const port = 3000;
app.listen(port);
console.log('Server is running on port 3000');

//POSTS

app.post("/Register", function (req, res) {
    const newUser = new User({
        email: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.password
    });

newUser.save(function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        res.render("Home")
    }
});
})
```

I've mirrored my angular routes for the express routes.

But when I click the register button, nothing happens, checking the console, no errors but no POST request is made.

What am I missing here? I've tried changing the gets in the server.js but no luck.

I'm wondering if it's got something to do with the fact angular is putting #! on the url for each view.

Do I need to set HTML5 mode to true in my angular route file?

My file structure for the views is public > views.

For now I'm just trying to get a basic username and password into the database, I will look at implementing passport and encryption at a later stage.

Comment: `const User = new mongoose.model("User", userSchema);` replace with `const User = new mongoose.Schema("User", userSchema);`

Comment: Still nothing. But yes, that line of code wasn't correct so thanks for that. But still when I click the register button, no POST is performed, no errors in the console, or errors on the command line.

Comment: I think it may be because I'm not actually using a submit button when sending the form. Will change that now and see if it solves the issue.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/universal have a look